# Could not find tools.jar

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

After running `npx react-native run-android`

I am getting this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unimodules-constants-interface:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261 contains a valid JDK installation.
```

Can anybody please explain what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's looking for a JDK while you're pointing to a JRE. Do you have an installed JDK? If so, maybe try pointing to that.

Comment: @sahdg Once you install your JDK you can update your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the new installation location. Then when any program looks for where java is installed it will check that location first.